Casting a tuple<int *, int, int, int*> to tuple<void*, int, int, void*> is causing an ASAN stack use out of scope issue
I have a code that is creating an ASAN stack use out of scope issue. Calling f() below will cause it.
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using TupleData = std::tuple<void *, int, int, void *>;

namespace
{
   int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3, v = 4; // file-scope variables. 
}

struct Data
{
   Data(const TupleData & tupleData) : m_tupleData(tupleData) {}

   const TupleData & m_tupleData;

   void execute()
   {
       void * int1 = std::get<0>(m_tupleData); // ASAN ISSUE IS BEING CAUGHT HERE : STACK USE AFTER SCOPE
   }
};

void f()
{       
   Data data(std::make_tuple(&x, y, z, &v)); 

   data.execute();
}

int main() {
    
    f();

    return 0;
}

I tried creating the tuple before passing it as a parameter instead and the issue stayed:
void f()
{       
   auto tupleData = {&x, y, z &v};

   Data data(tupleData); 

   data.execute();
}

After a lot of trials, I managed to make it succeed after modifying the function f() to explicitly create the tuple as a TupleData:
void f()
{       
   TupleData tupleData = {&x, y, z &v};

   Data data(tupleData); 

   data.execute();
}

Why would such an issue occur? I assume that casting from a tuple<int*, int, int, int*>  to tuple<void*, int, int, void*> should be valid.

Minor point: variables (in fact, all names) defined in the unnamed namespace are not global variables, despite the comment. They're file scope variables; their names are not accessible outside the source file where they're defined.

Usually having a reference data member is not a good idea. The pointed/referred to object can go out of scope and then the reference will be dangling. Also there are other errors in your code.

@PeteBecker Indeed. Thanks for the comment. They are basically global inside the file itself only.

Please post a [mcve].  This means the #include's and a main that calls your function.

@HusseinJaber -- "global inside the file" is "file scope", not global.

@user12002570 Which is exactly what's happening here, isn't it? The temporary created by make_tuple is destroyed as soon as the construction of data is finished, leaving the const ref dangling.

Also there are other errors in your code. Like the ctor and execute is private. Post a [mcve]

I've edited the code to make it compile. Thanks!

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes, exactly. Common mistake. I have some dupes for this. Basically, here the const ref doesn't extend lifetime of the temporary. Why lifetime of temporary doesn't extend till lifetime of enclosing object? and Why doesn't a const reference extend the life of a temporary object passed via a function?

Data data(std::make_tuple(&x, y, z, &v)); -- That temporary instance of the result of the make_tuple call is just that -- temporary.

Note that when I tried to do "auto tupleData = {&x, y, z &v}" instead of "TupleData tupleData = {&x, y, z &v};", the issue stayed, although it wasn't temporary. I had to explicitly specify its type to make it work

@OP See this answer and other dupes.

...although it wasn't temporary...  Another temporary is made, with the type TupleData.  I'd add code to disallow conversions of the tuple in the Data for its constructors.

Ahhhh yeah now it makes sense @Eljay. Since the type wasn't matching exactly, a temporary had to be created using the correct type TupleData, and then we go back to the original problem. Fair enough! Thanks everyone!

Question is this really representative of your code? If it is (meta)template code using std::tuple is fine, in all other cases you're better of making an explicit struct type. It is more readable and adds semantic meaning to your code (and the type-system)
